# Why [i] doesn't point to the starting point in a vector

Tags: r, loops

Why doesnt [i] point to the start of my vector?

```
tickers <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10)
tickers[i]
```

it prints

```
> tickers[i]
[1] 3
```

any ideas?

Comment: can you `print(i)`

Comment: > print(i)
[1] 3

Comment: that is why , setting`i=1`

Comment: if i set i=1 it then has corrected itself. How can it ever be set to 1=3? Another question, if i simple do tickers[1], whats the difference between that and tickers[i]?

Comment: You i=3 when you do tickers[i] it is equal to tickers[3]

Comment: Thx makes sense. tickers[i-3] lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you haven't input i = 3 somewhere earlier in the code? try the following

```
rm(i)
```

and then run the code, see what happens